# How can I style the LoadMoreButton component, getstream's react-activity-feed?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors, getstream-io

I am using getstream's `react-activity-feed`, react components to create activity and notification feeds using Stream. I would like to style the `LoadMoreButton` component, which is passed as the default prop for the `LoadMorePaginator` component.

What is the recommended approach to styling the `LoadMoreButton` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import an .scss file into your component to override default getstream component styles, for example:

```
.raf-load-more-button {
    padding: 0 8px;

    button {
      margin: {
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
      }
    }
  }
```

https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-react#customizing-styles